# TFS Builds with Java and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tfs, tfsbuild

I need to use TFS and Eclipse (Java Ant Project).

The TFS is offered by Microsoft (http://tfs.visualstudio.com) and I followed this instructions http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/build/setup-ci-build-in-eclipse/ .

But the builds always failed by don't show any error. With .NET project when a build failed the error is showed.

The information that I've in log is:

Overall Build Process

Get the Build

Update Build Number

Run On Agent (reserved build agent Hosted Build Agent)

Get the Build Directory

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationFolderPath)

Run TfsBuild for Configuration Folder

Getting sources

Labeling sources

Running Ant

C:\a\src\Tools\java\bin\java.exe -jar C:\a\src\Tools\ant\lib\ant-launcher.jar -buildfile C:\a\src\src\projectBuilder.xml -DBinariesRoot=C:\a\bin -DBuildDefinitionName="Hello World CI" -DBuildDefinitionUri=vstfs:///Build/Definition/2 -DBuildDirectory=C:\a -DBuildNumber="Hello World CI_20130422.15" -DDropLocation=$/HW/Drops -DLogLocation= -DSourceGetVersion=C90 -DTestResultsRoot=C:\a\TestResults -DTeamProject=HW -DWorkspaceName=WIN-50B0FC22RNF_2_40 -DWorkspaceOwner="LOCAL AUTHORITY\Elastic Build (remotemonitoring)"

Built $/HW/HW/projectBuilder.xml for default targets.

Generating list of changesets and updating work items

If CompilationStatus = Unknown

If TestStatus = Unknown

Set TestStatus to Succeeded

Anyone can use TFS with Eclipse, Java and Ant?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running junit tests?  Have you looked at the actual full log file, not just the summary view in the web browser?

Comment: No, first I want to build the project, the next step is running the junit tests.
Thanks for the tip, I look foward and give feedback!

Comment: OK, but what about the log file?

Comment: This project don't have (yet) junit test files.
You can see the log file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8156472/BuildLog.txt.

Comment: -DDropLocation=$/HW/Drops  -> The droplocation is the place, where the build puts the result, usually this is a network share folder. I don't think that the build can handle a TFS server path, because this would require to checkout/add/checkin files and maybe you "Elastic Build" account is also not permitted.

Comment: Hi MikeR.
In the Microsoft page where it is explained the CI process for Java and Eclipse (http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/build/setup-ci-build-in-eclipse/), the author place the Drop folder in the hosted team project... 
Your argument make sense, I will try it...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this question:
I uploaded the compiled jar file... Apparently the build agent can't overwrite this...

Solution: delete the jar file, and the build work!